# \imagegraphics doesn't interpret \ escape in filename

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to insert a background image with the beamer package using the following:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{/path/to_file/background.png}%
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my background file path has an underscore in it, as I put in the example above. (This is my home directory on OS X, so I can't really change it.) When I generate this via pandoc the resultant latex file has the underscore escaped with a \, so it looks like this:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{/path/to\_file/background.png}%
}
```

but this makes it impossible for includegraphics to find the file and so it fails at that point.

If I manually remove the \ from the latex, or move the file to, say, the root directory, so that there is no underscore in the path, all is well. Here's the exact error:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `/Users/my\_name/Downloads/background.png' not fou
nd on input line 102.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `/Users/my\T1\textunderscorename/Down
loads/background.png' not found: using draft setting.
```

So is there something I can do to tell includegraphics that the name is escaped, or to remove the escaping?

Here's the YAML:

```
--- 
name: John Doe 
backgroundImage: /Users/my_name/Downloads/background.png 
---
```

Text to add to template:

```
$if(backgroundImage)$ 
\usebackgroundtemplate{% 
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{$backgroundImage$}% 
}
```

Comment: What's your input format? Which pandoc version?

Comment: I'm using markdown and pandoc 2.2.1.

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Can you add the exact input and command used?

Comment: Use this YAML when the following text is in the template pandoc uses. The path to the background image has to have an underscore in it:  
  
 ---
 name: John Doe
 backgroundImage: /Users/my_name/Downloads/background.png
 ---



 $if(backgroundImage)$
 \usebackgroundtemplate{%
 \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{$backgroundImage$}%
 }

Comment: Please edit your question with these details, comments are a bad place to put code.

Answer (score 0):

YAML values are interpreted as Markdown, unless specified otherwise.  The `backgroundImage` is hence translated into LaTeX when used within `$backgroundImage$`.

The solution is to force literal interpretation of the input by telling pandoc that you know what you are doing, and that the input is already formatted as LaTeX:

```
---
name: John Doe 
backgroundImage: '`/Users/my_name/Downloads/background.png`{=latex}'
---
```

This is based on the [raw attribute extension](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute), which is enabled by default for pandoc flavored Markdown.

Comment: Yes, that was my ultimate solution, but I was hoping there was a latex way to get includegraphics to read an escaped underscore.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you could ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com